# Adding Key Value pair in JsonClass manually in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I have a Json Class where I want to add a key value pair manually. Below is the piece of code where i want to add a key with 0 count.
 `List<JsonClass> flows = new List<JsonClass>();
 flows.Add('KeyValue Pair Here');`

Comment: what is JsonClass ?

Comment: Show your `JsonClass`. If that is the `KeyPairValues` class, it would go something like this: `flows.Add(new JsonClass("Key","Value"));`

Comment: @DimitarTsonev Jsonclass is a class file created which is used to desirialize a json array

Comment: @FrankNielsen jsonclass is a class file containing json array elements. Thanks for your help. But it is not working

Comment: well, if you want help - then show your `JsonClass` in your post.